# How to get a widget in preference?

Tags: android, android-preferences

In Android, there are a lot of built-in preferences, such as `CheckBoxPreference`, `EditTextPreference`. Beside for these built-in preferences we can customize some preferences by extending `Preference` class. So can we get a widget in these preferences, such as `checkbox`, `edittext`?

Comment: Do you want to add checkbox,edit text etc to prference or what?

Comment: I want to retrieve the reference to the widget in preference.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're talking about are the widgets shown on the end of Preferences in the prefs screen, right? Android will let you set these widgets in your xml via the widgetLayout attribute:

```
<com.me.MyPreference
        android:key="my_key"
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/my_layout"
        android:title="@string/my_title"/>
```

or in code via a few functions, but doesn't provide much to access to the actual inflated layout at runtime (for instance, to update the state of a checkbox). Looking at the [CheckboxPreference](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.java#63) code, Google solves this by grabbing a reference to the widget in the Prefs [onBindView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#onBindView(android.view.View)) function:

```
@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    myWidget = (MyWidget) view.findViewById(R.id.my_widget);
}
```

then you can do what you want to the view later when the pref changes.